# Page doesn't contain a definition for X

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10

During development I had a `TempTextBlock` for testing and I've removed it now. It builds successfully, but when I try to create a package for store, it gives this error:

> error CS1061: 'MainPage' does not contain a definition for
>   'TempTextBlock' and no extension method 'TempTextBlock' accepting a
>   first argument of type 'MainPage' could be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly reference?)

In `MainPage.g.cs` I see this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Connect()
/// </summary>
[global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Build.Tasks"," 14.0.0.0")]
[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
public void Connect(int connectionId, object target)
{
    switch(connectionId)
    {
    case 1:
        {
            this.TempTextBlock = (global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBlock)(target);
        }
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    this._contentLoaded = true;
}
```

So `TempTextBlock` is used there. If I remove the whole method, it gives this error:

> error CS0535: 'MainPage' does not implement interface member
>   'IComponentConnector.Connect(int, object)'

What's that `Connect` method in `MainPage.g.cs` and how to resolve this issue? thanks.

Comment: What happens if you remove the this.TempTextBlock = ... and replaced it with continue;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For me in the future:
Delete entire `\obj' folder.

Visual Studio 2017 failed to create auto generated files for any reason.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Build > Clean Solution`  to clean all the auto generated code in your solution.